# How to select all rows from a table that have two other rows in the same table with timestamps within 30 minutes of the original row?

Tags: sql

As stated above, I'm trying to select all rows in a table where we see two other rows with timestamps (future looking) within 30 minutes of the current row. For example if we had a table:

```
TIMESTAMP           ID
7/20/2018 8:57:25   1
7/20/2018 8:59:25   2
7/20/2018 8:58:25   3
7/20/2018 9:57:25   4
7/20/2018 10:12:00  5
7/20/2018 10:12:15  6
```

We would return

```
TIMESTAMP           ID
7/20/2018 8:57:25   1
7/20/2018 9:57:25   4
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for?

Comment: Exactly 2 or at least 2?

Answer (score 0):

One solution which is suitable for `SQL Server`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    tmstmp datetime,
    id int
)

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('7/20/2018 8:57:25', 1),
('7/20/2018 8:59:25', 2),
('7/20/2018 8:58:25', 3),
('7/20/2018 9:57:25', 4),
('7/20/2018 10:12:00', 5),
('7/20/2018 10:12:15' , 6);

WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT
      id,
      tmstmp AS beg,
      DATEADD(minute, 30, tmstmp) AS fin 
   FROM
      tbl 
)
SELECT
   cte.beg AS [TIMESTAMP],
   cte.id AS ID 
FROM
   tbl 
   LEFT JOIN
      cte 
      ON tbl.tmstmp BETWEEN beg AND fin 
GROUP BY
   cte.id,
   cte.beg 
HAVING
   COUNT(*) > 2

|-------------------------|----|
| TIMESTAMP               | ID |
|-------------------------|----|
| 2018-07-20 08:57:25.000 | 1  |
| 2018-07-20 09:57:25.000 | 4  |
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jan beat me to it with a recursive look but here is another look at it with a select in the where clause (MS Sql Server):

```
declare  @timetables table ([timestamp] datetime, id int)

insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 8:57:25',   1)
insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 8:59:25' ,  2)
insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 8:58:25',   3)
insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 9:57:25',   4)
insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 10:12:00',  5)
insert into @timetables ([timestamp], id) values ('7/20/2018 10:12:15',  6)

select 
    *
FROM @timetables b
where 
(select 
    count(id) from @timetables b2 where 
    b2.id != b.id and  
    b2.timestamp > b.timestamp and 
    DateAdd(minute, 30, b.[timestamp]) > b2.timestamp) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple. Just look two rows ahead with `LEAD` and check whether that timestamp is still within 30 minutes.

You haven't told us your DBMS, so I am giving you a standard SQL query. Only the way to treat intervals may be different. One DBMS wants `interval '30' minute`, one wants `interval '30 minutes'` and yet another wants `interval 30 minute`. There are even DBMS that don't support intervals at all.

```
select timestamp, id
from
(
  select
    timestamp,
    id,
    lead(timestamp, 2) over (order by timestamp) as two_after
  from mytable t
)
where two_after <= timestamp + interval '30' minute
order by timestamp;
```

And you may have to quote the timestamp column, for this is an SQL word.